# Diploma translated to English in Germany

Tags: germany, student-visa

Is it generally admissible to apply to German masters programs that are taught in English with diploma that is apostiled and translated to English?

I haven't yet gotten it translated, but should it be translated by some special "sworn translator" to English?  (I am from Russia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes, but it is a bad idea, because you still need a translation to German" in my case.
The embassy requires translation of all document to German only.
So it's better to translate to German from the beginning. At least two copies: one for the university, the other is for embassy. They both don't return it.
Sworn translation is not necessary, and it is much longer.

Answer (score 1):

The anwer is probably yes. Probably because it still **may** depend on the particular diploma and university, especially if they allow application without uni-assist. However, in general case one will need to apply for master program in Germany through uni-assist.

On their web site, uni assist precisely lists the requirements for the translation of diploma:

https://www.uni-assist.de/en/how-to-apply/assemble-your-documents/educational-certificates/

If unclear, one still has a possibility to ask university / uni assist about further details.